# Como posso colocar uma variável dentro de uma string dos resources?

Tags: android, string, variáveis, resources

Como posso colocar uma variável dentro de uma string dos resources?

Eu tenho a seguinte string:

```
<resources>
    <string name="card_closed">O cartão Nº _var_ está fechado! </string>
</resources>
```

Como eu posso colocar ali a minha variável `_var_` programaticamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a resposta em inglês ([aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854647/how-to-put-variable-inside-string-resources)) e a referência ([aqui](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-format-strings--mobile-1775)), coloque esse código no xml:

```
<string name="meatShootingMessage">You shot %1$d pounds of meat!</string>
```

E assim no código:

```
 int numPoundsMeat = 123;
String strMeatFormat = getResources().getString(R.string.meatShootingMessage);
String strMeatMsg = String.format(strMeatFormat, numPoundsMeat);
```

**EDIT:**

Como pode-se ter várias variáveis dentro de um string.xml, elas são numerados e tipados. A % indica o número da variável, indicando a ordem na qual ela vai ser preenchida programaticamente. O $ define o tipo da variável. Como exemplificado nos links acima, pode ser $s para string, ou $d para um número.